# Is a one letter username insecure?

Tags: security, validation

We are building a secure application and were discussing the validation needed for a username.
It is clear that for a password that complexity rules must be established, yet for a username is it also true? 
Is it insecure to accept a one letter username? What are the security issues?

Answer (score 2):

In reality, the combination of user ID and password protect your system so *requiring* a 1-character ID gives attackers information they wouldn't otherwise have, hence less secure.

However, *allowing* a 1-character user ID is actually *more* secure than, say, a 10-character minimum, since the search space of an attacker is increased. In other words, the attacker has to check all possibilities between 1 and 9 characters _in addition to those 10 character or more.

The main problem with a 1-character ID is how you distinguish between Adam, Allan, Aaron and Alexandra :-)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the level of security you are trying to obtain. If this is for a website that allows the general public to view users usernames, than it would not make a difference. (example: a social network and on the users profile the username used to authenticate is included in the page header) as the username is already publicly accessable. However if this is not the case, then allowing one character usernames leads to easy username enumeration. 
A low-medium risk vulnerability (depending on the application), however it all depends on the level of compliance you are held to.

Does this have to pass any compliance testing? such as pci?

Edit: In short, yes you should require the username to be of a certain length, I would say 5 character minimum. My favorite thing to do is make their email for their username

Comment: I was with you up to the enumeration.  And I *hate* people who won't let me use my preferred 2-letter username.

Comment: You dont agree with my opinion on enumeration, or you don't know what I mean?

Comment: The thing is, I don't necessarily see it as a big deal, I just know from third party vulnerability assessments I have had to deal with in the past, that this can be an issue for some certifications, or internal security policies of third party companies that may be using the application.

Comment: I probably don't understand your claim.  Allowing shorter usernames creates more usernames, not fewer.   Other things being equal, more things are harder to enumerate.  Obviously you believe other things are *not* equal, but you might do better to articulate your position a little more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Context is always relevant ("secure from what?") but as someone who reviews applications for security professionally, it's almost always a bad idea to make usernames predictable, and one-character usernames are certainly predictable. Making usernames unpredictable to an attacker adds entropy for an attacker to deal with. Passwords ought to provide all of the entropy you'll ever need, but users are incredibly bad at choosing passwords with sufficient entropy. Even with password complexity requirements, the average user will just put in the bare minimum amount of effort to be validated ("P@ndab34R!" is not a great password).

If I know you allow or even require one-character usernames, as an attacker trying to get access to accounts, the first thing I'll do is: try password guessing for all single-character usernames, using a password dictionary (modified as needed to fit your password requirements). Chances are good that I'll get in. Once I'm in, how that might impact users depends on the kind of website it is. If it's a public website where anyone can register an account, it will just affect the user whose account I breached. If it's an authenticated website where I can't just register my own account at will, now I'm authenticated and able to attempt authenticated attacks on the site, which affects all users' security.

If you have weak requirements for usernames, you can try to offset that by boosting the authentication security in other areas such as:

- strong password requirements
- assign passwords to users rather than letting them choose their own
- strong account lockout mechanisms and/or human verification systems to deter brute-force attacks

Comment: Just to add to this: I recently assessed a financial website with a serious vulnerability that allowed authenticated users to view each other's confidential financial records. These records weren't accessible to unauthenticated users, and the registration process for new accounts (clients) was highly restricted. So this was a good example where lenient requirements on usernames could have easily affected the security of other users in a big way.